# Slot confirmation when giving a relative time to a AMAZON.TIME slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a slot, which has a confirmation prompt inside a pending Dialog set up like this:

```
Have I understood {desiredTime} correctly?
```

(where desiredTime = AMAZON.TIME)

The problem is, this slot should mainly be used for relative time input, e.g.:
"afternoon", "evening", "morning". 
These phrases will be parsed as "AF, MO" etc, so Alexa would always say "Have I understood AF correctly?" which is not what I would like to here.

Is there a way to make Alexa say "afternoon", "morning", "evening" without loosing the ability to also allow absolute time input?